# How to store and read a String out of a fixed-length byte array?

Tags: java

I have a byte array of a fixed length, and I want to store a String in it. Something like:

```
byte[] dst = new byte[512];
String foo = "foo";
byte[] src = foo.getBytes("utf-8");

for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    dst[i] = src[i];
}
```

But when I want to read the string value back out of dst, there's no way to know where the string terminates (guess there's no notion of null terminators in java?). Do I have to store the length of the string in the byte array, read it out separately to know how many bytes to read from the byte array?

Comment: Why are you copying from `src` to `dst` at all, and not using `src` itself?

Comment: Yes you should store the length of the String you're stuffing into dst otherwise how will you know how many bytes to pull again while reconstructing String from your dst byte array again.

Comment: `new String(dst, 0, src.length, "UTF-8")` and you could use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF8(String)` without bytes.

Comment: this code should throw buffer overflow error

Answer (score 7):

**1. `length`+`payload` scenario**

If you need to store string bytes into custom-length array, then you can use first 1 or 2 bytes for the notion of "length".

The code would look like:

```
byte[] dst = new byte[256];
String foo = "foo";
byte[] src = foo.getBytes("utf-8");
dst[0] = src.length;
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 1, src.length);
```

**2. `0` element scenario**

Or you can check the array, until you find a `0` element. But there's no guarantee that the first `0`-element you find is the one you need.

```
byte[] dst = new byte[256];
String foo = "foo";
byte[] src = foo.getBytes("utf-8");
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.length);
int length = findLength(dst);

private int findLength(byte[] strBytes) {
    for(int i=0; i< dst.length; ++i) {
        if (dst[i] == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**My choice:**

I would personally go with `length`+`payload` scenario.

Comment: Or the first 1 or 2 bytes can be used to tell how many following bytes is used for notion of length. This provides a much more expandable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your string with [Modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) encoding. This way you can use 0 as terminator.

But, if possible, you should stick to more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) for holding the data and length of data. A simple example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream dst = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String foo = "foo";
byte[] src = foo.getBytes("utf-8");
dst.write(src.length); // write length
dst.write(src); // write data
```

**TESTING:**

```
byte[] tmp = dst.toByteArray(); // length+data
byte[] newsrc = new byte[tmp[0]]; // tmp[0] is length
System.arraycopy(tmp, 1, newsrc, 0, tmp[0]); // copy data without length
System.out.println("Result str => " + new String(newsrc, "utf-8")); // create String again
//=> Result str => foo
```

*PS: This is a simple example, for real data handling it would be better to reserve 2 or more bytes for holding the length of the data you're storing.*